# How to get the propper line when using awk over a bunch of files?

Tags: awk

I have a bunch of markdown files and I want to get the filename and the line number where a pattern happens. I have tried something like:

```
awk '/pattern/ && NR > 7 {print FILENAME, NR, $0}' *.md
```

What happens is that awk considers all files as one and gives the wrong number. I also use **zsh** and I don't know what I am missing. I already have searched on the web with no avail.

The condition for listing the file is that the pattern happens after line seven in all markdown files.

Comment: awk has the internal variable `NR` which is the total `record number` of all records currently processed, accumulative over multiple files. There is also the internal variable `FNR` which is the record number of the current file. It is the latter you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FNR`, which is the record (line) number of the current input file.

```
awk '/pattern/ && FNR > 7 {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}' *.md
```

Comment: I did not know exactly the difference between FN and FNR and it is HUGE.